# How can I tell Windows to always start certain binaries with low priority?

Tags: windows, process, priority

I want to demote the priority of a number of processes that are auto-started on my corporate XP machine.  Is there a way that I can tell WinXP to always start a binary with low priority?

Comment: same question for windows7: https://superuser.com/q/102735/177522

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use [Prio](http://www.prnwatch.com/prio.html). It allows you to save your preferences for processes so they will launch with that priority the next time.

[image]

Prio is free for personal use.

If you don't want to install additional software, you can make batch scripts which open the specified executable via the `start` command. The `start` command takes switches which specify the priority to start the process with.

The priority switches are the same as the priorities available through task manager:

```
/LOW
/NORMAL
/HIGH
/REALTIME
/ABOVENORMAL
/BELOWNORMAL
```

Example:

```
start /low cmd.exe
```

This would start a cmd.exe instance with low priority.