# Save processes priority settings?

Tags: windows-7, process, task-manager, priority

Is there anyway to save the processes priority settings in Windows 7 instead of opening the task manager in every session and doing it manually?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[**Process Lasso**](http://www.bitsum.com/prolasso.php) can set sticky priorities, amongst other features.

> - ProBalance dynamic priority optimization
> - Works great for desktops, laptops, and netbooks
> - ***Persistent (sticky) priorities and CPU affinities***
> - Gaming mode
> - Instance count limits
> - Disallowed processes
> - High Performance Power Scheme processes
> - Anti-sleep processes
> - Keep processes running (auto-restart)
> - Unique system responsiveness graph
> - Differentiate between svchost.exe instances
> - Extremely low resource use
> - Stand-alone process management engine (uses as little as 1MB of RAM)
> - Both 32-bit and 64-bit builds for maximum efficiency
> - Event logging
> - MUCH more...

The basic version is free, and it works with Windows 32-bit and 64-bit.

[image]

---

There is also the great Task Manager addon: [**Prio (Priority Saver)**](http://www.prnwatch.com/prio.html) , but I'm not sure if it works with Windows 7 (Vista is the most recent listed).

> Prio will save the applied changes and
>   each time you start this process from
>   now on, it will set the saved priority
>   for it. You will not have to change
>   the priority manually any more

[image]

Comment: @Molly : did you test it on Win7?

Comment: On Windows 7 x86, yes

Comment: Prio doesn't seem to work for me in Win 7 x64, even after a reboot.

Comment: I also have issues with Prio on Win7 x64. It worked initially but seems to randomly stop working / disappear from the task manager.