# How to keep performance on minimized apps?

Tags: windows, windows-11

I use Windows 11 and use Ableton Live for music production. I noticed that when I toggle to another window or minimize Ableton's window, the performance of Ableton degrades to the point the sounds starts to stutter and break. When I put Ableton's window in front of the other windows, it start to play well again.

It's like Ableton's CPU priority is high when its window is on top, but when I put another window in front of it, its priority goes down.

Is there any setting in Windows 11 to prevent this to happen? I want the performance of an application to be the same regardless its window is in front or not.

Answer (score 0):

Windows generally 'nices' the process with the focus on its window (ie. that is in front).

Try setting the process's task priority to *high* or *realtime*. You can use the Task Manager to change the priority on the *Processes* tab. There are a lot of alternative tools as well.

As with any such manual settings: test well before actually using in production.

Comment: No, not realtime. High yes, but realtime is a no. That can crash your system. Especially if you talk like something like Ableton that can be extremely CPU intensive. https://superuser.com/questions/1380473/what-happens-if-i-set-single-threaded-process-to-realtime-priority-on-multicore#:~:text=Setting%20a%20CPU-intensive%20process,not%20even%20the%20task%20manager.

Comment: I guess it's worth a try - obviously no good if the machine is underpowered.

Comment: Okay, I'm sorry, but I have to vote down your answer now with a remark like this. I'm a mucisian myself and what you're suggesting can literally cause one to lose an hour of work that just can't be redone. If you really want to suggest realtime, then add to your answer what the risks are so that they won't work with realtime on a project that they don't mind risk losing. And yes, I'm talking about the risk of a file corruption during autosave where the CPU freezes and Ableton becomes unresponsive and ends, and the entire project is gone. Happened to me a few times.