# have imagemagick not use up CPU?

Tags: imagemagick

I am on windows (7) and i'd like to have imagemagick make a thumb. I'm using append so it isnt doing one file at a time but many. I figured out how to limit the memory usage (`-limit area`). I don't suppose i can do the same for CPU can i? I know i can make it use more then one thread/core for more speed but i'm planning to run it on machines with one cpu and would rather not have it use up all the cpu power.

Also i am spawning the process via Process class in .NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most operating systems allow you to set priority values (or equivalent) for processes. This effectively limits the degree to which that process can use CPU time in competition with other processes.

See https://stackoverflow.com/q/1374817/477035

Comment: The mentioned StackOverflow is only useful for developers. I assume the the similar question from Superuser will help acidzombie24 more: http://superuser.com/questions/83148/how-can-i-tell-windows-to-always-start-certain-binaries-with-low-priority

Comment: @Robert, that is a better answer for SU. acidzombie24 did say he/she was using .Net's Process class (i.e. VB or C# programming)

Comment: Thanks this is perfect. I completely forgot about that command in process (maybe bc i found out it didnt work on linux or something) and was thinking about something like linux `nice` but on windows. But yes this completely answers it +1 and accepted. Also CC @Robert